# Image not fully responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and have an image 1920x1280. It is currently responsive only till about a width of 1000 px and stops shrinking from there. Width below 1000 px, it starts to cut off the side of the image. I need the full image to be visible on any device. I am adding the image via CSS background url. Is there a way around this. Added the relevant code below. The image is placed within the ID 'intro'.

Image

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="intro">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <h1 style="color: #000000">Title<span class="brand-heading">Quote</span></h1>
          <p style="color: #000000" class="intro-text">Short description</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-default page-scroll">Learn More</a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#intro .intro-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#intro .intro-body H1 {
    font-size: 76px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
#intro {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
#intro .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
}
```

Comment: The following is just a note and has nothing to do with your question: 3-digit hex colour values are buggy in some older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this Style instead of your id intro. There are two methods. One is with fixed height and width the other one is without width and height.

```
#intro{
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url('../img/intro-bg.jpg');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

or

```
#intro{
background-image:url('../img/intro-bg.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**background-size: cover;** try to fill all background space so maybe cutoff edge of image. If you will show image completely without cut off set **background-size** to **contain**.

```
background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat right bottom scroll;
background-color: #31f1fd;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-o-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: Contain does keep the image fully visible but it makes the image smaller with a black border on its sides.

Comment: background-color: #000; cause black border. I change code, please try again. @kar

Comment: You are right, it was the background color. But the image responsiveness issue pretty much the same. After width of 1000px, image starts to cut off. At 768px, image becomes fully visible again. Below that width, starts to cut off again.